# File synchronization with only using ssh/scp

Tags: linux, synchronization, ssh, scp

Is it possible doing synchronization with usig only ssh and scp? If yes, how?
thank you...

Comment: And how is this related to programming?

Comment: I guess anything that you write on linux terminal is a program. Am I wrong? In addition, I don't need that anymore, thank you for your helpfull answer!...

Comment: This is very useful as a programming tool, I tend to use virtual machine to host my dev servers, this allows you to have your code in your machine so you dont get problems with your editor, git... and instantly replicated in the virtual machine to be used by your servers

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Personally I want to do this to program on a remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you are looking for is [SSH Fuse](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/sshfs.html).

It's a file system based on ssh, there is good libraries for various operative systems.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to sync directories between machines is [rsync](http://rsync.samba.org/).

Comment: i know that kind of programs, but i want to learn if it can be done by using ssh/scp